# Contact Form 7 - Center the Input Fields

Tags: css, wordpress, input, contact-form-7

I have a Contact form 7 on my home page here: http://grownowsma.com/

I have been trying to get the input fields to be centered. I tried a few tricks I've used before and answers from other Stack Overflow questions and for some reason no luck.

I tried this trick: http://www.screencast.com/t/ygBP3eQn9jQu

I tried these in the CSS:

```
.contactform input[type="text"],form .contactform input[type="email"]{
    margin: 9px auto 0 !important;
}
```

And this:

```
.wpcf7-form-style {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
    display: block;
}
```

Both no luck. I've been messing around in the inspector for a while and haven't been able to change it. Any other suggestions for selectors or attributes to try?

Comment: Add style="margin: 0 auto;" to both input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an element with the class `contactform`, so you can't select inputs beneath it. Either add that around the form shortcode in your post, or use a different selector e.g. `.home .wpcf7-form input[type="text"], .home .wpcf7-form input[type="email"]` assuming you don't add a second CF7 form on the homepage where you don't want to center the inputs.

Other than that, `margin: auto;` should work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it globally, use  this CSS:

```
.f7-form-control, input[type="text"].wpcf7-form-control,input[type="email"].wpcf7-form-control, input[type="password"].wpcf7-form-control, input[type="tel"].wpcf7-form-control, textarea.wpcf7-form-control,.post-password-form input[type='password'],input[type="email"] {
    margin: auto;
}
```

If you want for only a page then you can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-add-custom-css/ . It will give you a option to put custom css in individual page.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your contact form ID is: 4579
And here is the CSS for that specific form only.

```
#wpcf7-f4579-p4004-o1 .wpcf7-text{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked for me:

```
label, .wpcf7-submit{
    margin-left: 50% !important;
}
```

You can also add a `<div style="text-align:center">` directly in your form if you want.

Answer (score -1):

Please add in you style.css:

```
.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-validates-as-required {
    margin-left: 250px !important;
}
```